# Motion tracking : setting parameter for multiple selected trackers

Tags: tracking

I have 20 trackers which need to be re-tracked and i want to change the method from  'loc' to 'Affine'. But how to set this for all the trackers at once ? i can select multiple trackers but the parameter only apply to single active tracker only. Of course if possible, i don't want to do this one by one for all those 20 trackers.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you not to treat all trackers the same. Not all trackers need to be in a single mode, some work better with perspective, some with loc rot, some with loc rot scale. It all depends on the kind of motion you are tracking and how the particular tracked feature moves in the video and the item's visibility. If you are learning, think of trackers as individual processes. Supervise the behavior of each tracker individually to learn how to get more accurate results.

And to answer the question, no there is no easy way to select all trackers and change the motion model for multiple trackers. It could probably be done by scripting.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use a script to edit a collection of trackers en masse and, e.g., change the associated motion model.

First, open the Python Console. You can do this by changing to the Scripting workspace, if you have one; or simply change the editor type for an area on your screen. Then, you need to pick the motion model you want to change each track to. The options are documented in [the blender API docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.MovieTrackingTrack.html#bpy.types.MovieTrackingTrack.motion_model). If, for example, you want to change them all to use the Affine model, you can enter the following:

```py
tracks = D.movieclips['YOUR_CLIP_HERE'].tracking.objects['Camera'].tracks
for track in tracks:
     track.motion_model = 'Affine'
```

Note that you'll need to modify `'YOUR_CLIP_HERE'` to match the name of the clip in question, and if you're tracking an object rather than the camera, you'll need to change `'Camera'` to match the name of that tracking object.